# jquery ui spinner after ajax call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, delegates

I'm trying to use the jquery ui spinner on forms dynamically inserted through ajax calls.
To handle ajax calls I'm relying on [ajaxy](http://balupton.github.com/jquery-ajaxy/demo/).

On success I call this function like so:

```
response: function(){
    var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy; var data = this.State.Response.data; var state = this.state;
    var State = this.State;
    var Action = this;
    Action.documentReady($content);

    updater(); // THE FUNCTION TO BIND NEW ELEMENTS

    return true;
},
```

Here's the function

```
function updater(){
$('.spin').spinner();
}
```

And this works without any problem. But then When I call that same function on "normal" jquery requests (not ajaxy ones), it doesn't work anymore:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType:"json",
        success: function(res) {
            updateTarget(res,target,animation);
            updater();
        }
    }
});
```

I really don't see why in one case it is working, while in the other it isn't...

Comment: Have you checked for scope problems?

Comment: Is something in `updateTarget()` failing?

Comment: No, I'm sure there aren't bugs before the execution of `updater()`, I have even put an `alert()` to see if it was executing and it showed up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out... My error was that I was running `updater()` after `updateTarget(res,target,animation);`, which is the function that analyses the json response and attach html elements to the page, while I must run `updater()` inside `updateTarget(res,target,animation);` right after the attachment to the page through `.html()`.